# PHP query when a user submit a form select

Tags: php, post, select, input, submit

I want to delete a row from a form select when i click on submit input with an sql query,(i think i am wrong on something, but i don't understand what) as you can see below for my example :

- [My list and the blue case i want to delete on submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v82aC.png)
- My actual code, and the $supp i want to do when the user click on submit

`

```
<form method="POST">
        <select>
            <?php
            // Drop Down
            $res = null;
            $sql2 = "SELECT `sinistre_type` FROM `form_sinistre`";
            $query2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
            $query2->execute();

            // INIT > PREP > EXEC > SUPP
            $supp = "DELETE FROM `form_sinistre` WHERE `sinistre_type` = '$res'";
            $query3 = $db->prepare($supp);
            $sendbddsupp = $query3->execute();
    
            echo "<option disabled selected>..Choix Possible..</option>\n";
            while ($res = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
                echo "<option name='res'>" . $res[0] . "</option>\n";
            }

            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Supprimer">
    </form>
```

`

- Some $_POST config

`

```
<?php
session_start(); //debut de SESSION
include("config.php"); //Appel de la bdd

// ... INIT VARIABLES ...
$sinistre_type = "";
$sinistre_desc_dmg = "";
$list = "";


if (empty($_POST)) { // SANS COOKIES / POST

} else { // AVEC COOKIES / POST
    $sinistre_type = $_POST['nom'];
    $sinistre_desc_dmg = $_POST['vent'];
    $res = $_POST['res'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `form_sinistre` (sinistre_type, sinistre_desc_dmg) VALUES (:sinistre_type, :sinistre_desc_dmg)";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':sinistre_type' => $sinistre_type, ':sinistre_desc_dmg' => $sinistre_desc_dmg));
}

var_dump(isset($_POST['res']));

?>
```

`

(EDIT : my list is linked with my db and working that why i want to send sql query)

Thanks by advance for your help, if you need more information let me know :)

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Please also read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Anyway you seem to be trying to do the DELETE when the form is loading. You need to do it when the form is submitted, so you can read the selected value from $_POST.

Comment: @ADyson Done, thank you for your advise, yes am trying to DELETE when the form is submitted, what do you mean by read the selected value from $_POST ? i tried to var_dump $res but nothing happend

Comment: You have no name parameter on your `<select>`, so that's why you can't find that form variable. `var_dump($_POST)` to see what comes in from the form.

Comment: That's because `$res` is null. you never populate it. `what do you mean by read the selected value from $_POST ?` ... I mean e.g. `if (!empty($_POST)) { $selectedID = $_POST["something"]; ...etc` . But currently your `<select>` doesn't even have a name so its value won't be sent to the server. I suggest you take a HTML / PHP forms tutorial, you seem to lack some of the basic understanding required to build a form.

Comment: Also it's unclear why you showed us the second piece of code (under the "Some $_POST config) - that appears to be processing a different form where you add items to the table. It has nothing to do with the form you showed us, and nothing to do with deleting. But...it should give you a clue how to process the deletion form, it would be a similar approach. (And the HTML for that insertion form would show you the general approach for creating the form correctly too). That said you still need to study the basic concepts so you actually understand what all the bits of it mean.

Comment: `echo "<option name='res'>" . $res[0] . "</option>\n";` this one you mean ? (name='res')

Comment: `<option>` s don't have names. `<select>`s have names. `<option>`s should have a `value` though. This is what I mean - study the basics please before you get yourself even more confused. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: ho ok yes i am novice in php and learning it, i will check the basics, thank you for the link ;)

Comment: To develop web applications you need to learn HTML (at minimum, maybe some CSS and JavaScript too) as well as PHP